# Breezejs "object is not a function" leads to "Uncaught Error: There is no metadata available for this query"- When I am trying to make my data prime

Tags: breeze, hottowel

I am developing a demo application using HotTowel SPA in VS2012 using breezejs.
The error " Uncaught Error: There is no metadata available for this query" which is not occurring always but sometimes when I am trying to Prime the data (I am calling prime method on initial page load which is basically a simple query), for querying. Sometimes application fails to load and gives the error but on other hand it doesn't fails -it works.

Here is that code

```
 function primeData() {
        var promise = Q.all([
        getLookups(),
        getAllContactDetails(null, true)])
           .then(applyValidators);

        return promise.then(success);

        function success() {

            datacontext.lookups = {

                       // code to populate lookups 
            };
            log('Primed data', datacontext.lookups);

        }

        function applyValidators() {
            model.applyJobValidators(manager);
        }

    }
```

The above function gives the following error

**"TypeError: object is not a function↵    at querySu…lush (http://localhost:52356/scripts/Q.js:106:17)", message: "object is not a function"}message: "object is not a function"stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }set stack: function () { [native code] }__proto__: Error"**

Which leads my application not to work properly, Can anyone suggest what small mistake I am committing while making my data prime, which is forcing my application to misbehave.

```
function getLookups() {

        var abc = EntityQuery.from('Lookups');

        return manager.executeQuery(abc)
            .fail(queryFailed1);
    }
    function queryFailed1()
    {
        //logError
    }
```

var getAllContactDetails = function (contactObservable, forceRemote) {

```
        if (!forceRemote) {
            var s = getLocal('Contact_Details');
            if (s.length > 3) {
               // s.pop();
                contactObservable(s);
                debugger;
                return Q.resolve();
            }
        }
        var query = EntityQuery.from('Details');
        debugger;
        return manager.executeQuery(query)
                    .then(querySucceeded)
                    .fail(queryFailed2);

        function queryFailed2() {
         //   log
        }


        function querySucceeded(data) {

            contactObservable(data.results);

            toastr.success("Contacts loaded!")

            log('Retrieved [' + entityNames.detail + '] from remote data source',
                data, true);


        }
    };
```

Comment: Obviously, the error message comes from the Q library, which means you have something wrong in either; `getLookups` or `getAllContactDetails` . you may want to post the code for both.

Comment: Now check I copied the remaining code , here what I am facing is if I am loading another view instead of home view, then metadata is processed and though its available home page works and fetches everything I needed, but if I try to load home page directly, it will show no metadata error. Is there any function which I should use instead of 'Q.all' which can actually wait until my metadata gets populated.

Comment: As for the error, you're passing `null` to `contactObservable` . How do you expect it to receive data as a function if you're not passing anything?? for the metadata error, it depends on where you're calling the `primeData` function?

Comment: Thanks @Adel Sal, I did used a temporary observable variable, some error is fixed but still sometimes I am getting "Uncaught Error: There is no metadata available for this query".